# Force ships to use warp

Tags: endless-space

Is there any way to force a ship to use its warp drive to get to a location, instead of using the normal routes? There's an enemy system I'd like to scan without losing my ship, but I can't get it close enough without actually trying to go to the system. If I route my ship to a nearby system, the path always goes through the enemy system even though that means certain death.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you've unlocked the proper technology (Atmospheric Filtration in the standard tech tree), you can order your ships to move directly to a planet with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Hold it down while ordering the movement, and your ships will (slowly!) make a beeline for the system in question.

Comment: Oh cool, I'd tried it with shift and given up.